# Python create folder tree

Tags: python, directory

sorry for the simple question, but i dont know how to solve my easy problem. I would like to create a folder tree. I am selecting the main folder and create the first level of subfolder. But I dont know how to create the second level of folders nested in some of the first level.

Example:
MAIN FOLDER (SELECTED) contain the folders A,B and C
the folder A should contain the folder A1
the folder C should contain the folder C1

```
import pathlib

from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

folder = ["A", "B", "C"]

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.update()

c_path = askdirectory(title='Select Main Folder')
path = c_path + "/"

root.destroy()

for i in folder: 
    pathlib.Path(path + i).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) 

print("done")
```

Comment: What's the output that you are getting?

Comment: It's easy if you have all the folders in a flat list: `["A", "A/A1", "B", "C", "C/C1" ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a second list (`subfolders`) providing your sub directory names:

```
import pathlib

from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

folder = ["A", "B", "C"]
subfolders = ["1", "2", "3"]

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.update()

c_path = askdirectory(title='Select Main Folder')
path = c_path + "/"
root.destroy()

for f in folder:
    for s in subfolders:
        subDir = f+s
        pth = pathlib.Path(path) / f / subDir
        pth.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        print(pth, pth.exists())

print("done")
```

Out:

```
/private/tmp/nestedPath/A/A1 True
/private/tmp/nestedPath/A/A2 True
/private/tmp/nestedPath/A/A3 True
/private/tmp/nestedPath/B/B1 True
/private/tmp/nestedPath/B/B2 True
/private/tmp/nestedPath/B/B3 True
/private/tmp/nestedPath/C/C1 True
/private/tmp/nestedPath/C/C2 True
/private/tmp/nestedPath/C/C3 True
done
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks to all! I just take the inspiration to finalize the excercise. I guess is not so nice but still work.

```
import pathlib
import os
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

folder = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

subfolder_A = ["/a1"]
subfolder_B =  ["/b1", "/b2", "/b3"]
subfolder_F = ["/f1", "/f2"]

root = Tk()
root.update()

c_path = askdirectory(title='Select Main Folder') # shows dialog box and return the path
path = c_path + "/"

root.destroy()

for i in folder: 
    pathlib.Path(path + i).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) 

for f in subfolder_A:
    pathlib.Path(path + folder[0] + f).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        
for g in subfolder_B:
    pathlib.Path(path + folder[3] + g).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    
for h in subfolder_F:
    pathlib.Path(path + folder[5] + h).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        
os.startfile(path)

print("folder tree created")
```